# How to type the modified parallel (leftmerge) symbol in LaTex

Tags: symbols

How to type [image] in LaTex? I found it here:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\begin{document}
$\llceil\rrceil\llfloor\rrfloor$
\end{document}
```